# Checking if files exist in some remote folders with bash

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to do a script to look in some folders and send an email if there are files in these folders.
I've tried to do something like this but I get errors with the command variable and print of the folder.

```
for folder in "FOLDER1" "FOLDER2";  do
  command=`ssh -q user@host "ls /usr/local/username/`{print $folder}` | wc -l"`
  #echo $command

  if [ $command -ne '0' ]
  then
    #send error email 
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with:

```
command=$(ssh -q user@host 'ls "/usr/local/username/'$folder'" | wc -l')
```

You can't really nest backticks (and I'm not sure why you wanted to to that anyway).

Answer (score 2):

This can be a lot simpler. I have no idea what you're tring to do with `{print $folder}`: the braces don't make any sense here, and if you're trying to include `$folder` in the string, you would just write `$folder`. [You should not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), it's very rarely useful and often fails.

```
if ! ssh user@host "test -e '/usr/local/username/$folder'"; then
  # the file doesn't exist
```

Note that the file name must be quoted for the remote shell. I mostly took care of this in my command above, by surrounding the file name in the remote command with single quotes, but that only works if `$folder` itself does not contain any single quotes. If your local shell is bash, ksh93 or zsh, use this instead, to quote any single quote:

```
q=\'\\\'\'
if ! ssh user@host "[ -d '/usr/local/username/${folder//\'/$q}' ]"; then
```

Another approach which is usually more convenient is to mount the remote filesystem with [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) and work on it through the normal filesystem interface. I recommend this unless you're working with a lot of remote servers at the same time.

```
mkdir /path/to/mount/point
sshfs user@host /path/to/mount/point
if ! [ -d "/usr/local/username/$folder" ]; then
```